# change sprite os a Rectangle in LIBGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx, sprite

So I have a Rectangle and I want to change its sprite 90 degrees clockwise without changing its position.

Here's what I got:

```
    //sprites I want to use
    Up = new Texture("left.png");
    Down = new Texture("right.png");
    Left = new Texture("down.png");
    Right = new Texture("up.png");

    //the Rectangle
    square = new Rectangle();
    square.x = 630;
    square.y = 720 / 2 - 32 /2;
    square.width = 32;
    square.height = 32;
```

on the render()

```
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Right, square.x, square.y);
    batch.end();
```

and so with that I want to change the Rectangle sprite with the sprites above.
I'd appreciate some help!

Comment: SpriteBatch has a method for drawing a texture or texture region with a rotation (about the bottom left corner). So draw it with the degrees of rotation and some offset to account for where the bottom left corner should be to maintain the position you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will help you to actually create sprites with your textures. So for example:

```
Sprite upSprite = new Sprite(Up)
```

The sprite origin will automatically be at the bottom left corner, and will rotate around that point. To set the origin to the middle of the sprite:

```
upSprite.setOriginCenter()
```

Then to rotate the sprite 90 degrees you can do:

```
upSprite.setRotation(90)
```

Now you can draw it the same, however I'd recommend updating the sprite position:

```
upSprite.setPosition(square.x, square.y)
```

That way you only need to do

```
 upSprite.draw(batch)
```

For more information check the [Sprite documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html).

Comment: thanks!! so if i wanted to make it rotate when i touch the screen what would i have to add? is it like:

`if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
      upSprite.setRotation(90);
}`

Comment: It would be easier to look for a touchDown or touchUp event so that you only call it once. Take a look at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling. The inputProcessor should do what you need

Comment: yh I got it working thanks once again!! but if i touch it, it only turns one time, what do i have to add so that it turns everytime it touch the screen?

Comment: `setRotation(degrees)` is going to set it to whatever degrees you specify (right now it will just keep it at the same 90° every time you click). So if you want it to rotate each time, you will need to modify `degrees` each time accordingly.

Comment: thank you so much for the help and your time!! I got it working